# SELinux policy for Android emulator

Tags: qemu, android, selinux, emulation

The Google Android emulator requires `execheap` permissions, otherwise it segfaults when SElinux is in enforcing mode. For those who are not familiar with the Android emulator: It uses a forked version of qemu.

The two easy solutions are

- `setenforce 0`
- `setsebool -P allow_execheap 1`

Obviously, those are far from ideal from a security perspective. Also, hoping for a patch so the emulator does not need execheap might take a very long time.

In my audit logs, I found that the offending process was indeed `qemu-system-x86_64-headless`, however, the bundled binary and not the "original" one. Therefore, the labels differ.

```
semanage fcontext --list | grep qemu-kvm
/usr/bin/qemu-kvm                                  regular file       system_u:object_r:qemu_exec_t:s0
```

```
ls -laZ /root/android_sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 31174856 Aug  1 16:32 qemu-system-x86_64-headless
```

Other reports where `execheap` was the issue pointed to GPU drivers. The machine I'm running on has neither a GPU nor iGPU. The Vulkan device used is Swiftshader.

Unfortunately, I am completely new to SElinux.

- Do I need to write a custom policy for the emulator? How? And how do I run it with said policy?
- Is labeling the executable(s) enough? How do I do that?
- How else can I make it work without enabling execheap globally or setting SElinux to permissive mode?